# Refreshing parent page after child window is closed dynamics 2011

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011

This is in the context of Microsoft Dynamics 2011. I am opening a webresource using showModalDialog. This question is strictly for IE. I have tried using window.unload to refresh the parent page after modal dialog is closed, using this code:

```
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
      function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
```

and have also tried polling the modal page's closed status from the parent page using setInterval, and triggering refresh when it is closed, but none seem to work. Was wondering if anyone had any ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a word of caution:  **`showModalDialog()` is deprecated in all modern browsers.**  And while it does function in IE (including in version 11), it is not supported in Edge.  It's only a matter of time before you will need to change this implementation.  I strongly suggest you consider an alternative solution that does not use this method.

That said, if you do decide to use `showModalDialog()`, consider assigning the function call to a variable.  From the modal page, you can assign to the `window.returnValue` property to pass whatever data you'd like.

Within your main page code, you can then check the value of your variable, and take action accordingly.  Here's one way to do that:

#### Main Page:

```
var returnedFromModal = window.showModalDialog(/* your options here*/);
if (returnedFromModal) {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

#### Modal:

```
/* ... other modal-related code ...*/
window.returnValue = true;
```

Further documentation can be found here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog